# YAML DUMP USING C++

Tags: ros, c++, yaml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do i dumb my param values into a yaml file using C++? I tried system("rosparam dump example.yaml"); but no luck..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267467/yaml-dump-using-c++/) by [MechLc](https://answers.ros.org/users/29880/mechlc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @MechLc!

You say it doesn't work because you can't see the `example.yaml` file that should be generated, right?

The `rosparam dump example.yaml` will generate the file on the current working directory.

In order to see the current working directory, you can use the `pwd` command, like: `system(" echo 'ROS Params dumped at: ' $(pwd); rosparam dump example.yaml");`

Or you can pass the full path of the yaml file, like: `rosparam dump /full/path/to/example.yaml`.

Below I have attached a code of a ROS Node in CPP that just dumps the ros params.

If you run the node using `roslaunch`, the file is going to be generated probably on  `~/.ros/example.yaml`, as you can see on this video (https://youtu.be/w5cVKlhy37w).

```
#include <ros/ros.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    
    ros::init(argc, argv, "tutorial_node");
    
    system(" echo 'ROS Params dumped at: ' $(pwd); rosparam dump example.yaml");
    
    ros::spin();
    
    return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) with karma: 1038 on 2017-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0